# How to list socket options of running processes?

Tags: linux, tcp, sockets

Is there a convenient way (e.g. a readily-available command or a program that I can write using standard system calls) to list socket options (e.g. TCP_NODELAY) of an open TCP socket of some running process on a Linux system?

Comment: This is a good question!  The standard command **should** be `lsof -T f`, see the Manual page here, http://linux.die.net/man/8/lsof. However, running that on many Linux (I tried Debian, Arch, Kubuntu) returns: *lsof: unsupported TCP/TPI info selection: f*.

Comment: And, BTW, `knetstat` **does** work flawlessly on  run-of-the-mill Debian Jessie. and Arch Linux.

Comment: Related question on Stackoverflow that has a systemtap based answer: [See socket options on existing sockets created by other apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15243049/427158)

Answer (score 2):

I have not personally done this myself, but it looks like [knetstat](https://github.com/veithen/knetstat) may be able to help you.  It is not readily-available, but unfortunately I am not sure there is such a way.